# py2App throwing exception: 'unknown mach-o header'

Tags: python, macos, py2app, mach-o

trying to use py2app on my ubuntu machine to generate an mac app.  Running into problems at the last stage.

```
  File "...lib/python3.9/site-packages/macholib/MachO.py", line 167, in load_header
    raise ValueError("Unknown Mach-O header: 0x%08x in %r" % (header, fh))
ValueError: Unknown Mach-O header: 0x7f454c46 in <_io.BufferedReader name='/usr/local/lib/python3.9/lib-dynload/_asyncio.cpython-39-x86_64-linux-gnu.so'>
```

here;s what my setup file looks like:

from setuptools import setup

```
APP = ['zer.py']
DATA_FILES = ['emailSearchCriteria.txt', 'mapFields.txt']
OPTIONS = {
  'packages': ['bs4', 'googleapiclient', 'httplib2', 'google_auth_oauthlib', 'lxml']

#  'packages': ['bs4', 'lxml']
}

setup(
    app=APP,
    data_files=DATA_FILES,
    options={'py2app': OPTIONS},
    setup_requires=['py2app'],
)
```

Comment: wait: just realized that p2app needs to be run on a mac.

Answer (score 1):

p2App needs to be run on a mac to work